# In this linked list method I try to add a item in sorted order, but I am getting a null pointer exception

Tags: java, list, linked-list

```
    public void addNode(Car newCarEntry){
    ListNode currentNode;
    ListNode previousNode;
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(newCarEntry);

    if (head == null || newCarEntry.isNewerThan(head.carItem)){
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }else{
        currentNode = head.next;
        previousNode = head;
        while(currentNode != null &&      !newCarEntry.isNewerThan(currentNode.carItem)){
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
            previousNode = currentNode;
        }
        newNode.next = currentNode;
        newNode = previousNode.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ListNode?what does it do?

Comment: @Artur Vieira, could you provide the fully qualified name of ListNode, I think it may be deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You have a mistake in the way you advance the pointers.
Change:

```
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        previousNode = currentNode;
```

to

```
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
```

Your way you make both currentNode and previousNode holding references to the same object, which is not what you want.

**EDIT:**
Also your last line should be

```
    previousNode.next =  newNode;
```

insead

```
    newNode = previousNode.next;
```

because you are not attaching the new node to the list this way.

Comment: Got another question fiver. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558658/in-this-method-i-keep-getting-a-return-value-of-one-even-after-i-add-more-nodes