# In this method I keep getting a return value of One even after I add more nodes

Tags: java, list, linked-list

Got a quick question, this is part of a linked list. It determines what the size of the list is, it doesnt work very well at the moment because it keeps returning a 1 even after I add more nodes.

```
public int size(){
ListNode currentNode = null;
ListNode previousNode = null;
int numberOfNodes = 0;

if (head == null) return 0;

previousNode = head;
currentNode = head.next;

numberOfNodes++;

while (currentNode != null){
    previousNode = currentNode;
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
    numberOfNodes++;
}
return numberOfNodes;

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of previousNode in your method? It is not doing anything. Can we see your addNode method too?

Comment: I really think the problem is in the add node function which you haven't provided...

Answer (score 2):

If the addNode function is as the one in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558511/in-this-linked-list-method-i-try-to-add-a-item-in-sorted-order-but-i-am-getting/6558522#6558522) then you have an error:

Last line should be

```
    previousNode.next = newNode;
```

instead of

```
    newNode = previousNode.next;
```

Answer (score 0):

Too much clutter in this code, try the following:

```
public int size() {
  int numberOfNodes = 0;
  ListNode currentNode = head;
  while (currentNode != null){
    numberOfNodes++;
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
  }
  return numberOfNodes;
}
```